# How to test window.location in Jest Redux

Tags: reactjs, testing, redux, jestjs

my redux action is changing window.location. Unfortunately my attempts have not worked.

I have a basic action that changes window.location. If I set a console log within the action, it's correct.

But when I console log the action within jest, it's not correct.

screenActions.test.js

```
store.dispatch(actions.loadScreen())
console.log(window.location) // does not produce a string, rather the location object
```

screen.actions.js

```
export const loadScreen = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
   ....

   window.location = 'www.google.com';
   console.log(window.location) // produces 'www.google.com'

   ....
};
```

Any tips or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From the top of my head, you could try to define setter/getter spies for window.location so that you would know when the values changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [doc](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#reconfiguring-the-jsdom-with-reconfiguresettings):

> The top property on window is marked [Unforgeable] in the spec, meaning it is a non-configurable own property and thus cannot be overridden or shadowed by normal code running inside the jsdom, even using Object.defineProperty.

But, we can use `Object.defineProperty()` to define getter/setter for `window.location` with our own property `_href`. Besides, it seems you are using `redux-thunk` middleware, the `loadScreen` is an asynchronous action creator, you need to use `await` to wait for the completion of the asynchronous code.

E.g.

`screen.actions.js`:

```js
export const loadScreen = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  window.location = 'www.google.com';
  console.log(window.location);
};
```

`screen.actions.test.js`:

```js
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import * as actions from './screen.actions';

const mws = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureStore(mws);

describe('67339402', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
      set(val) {
        this._href = val;
      },
      get() {
        return this._href;
      },
    });
    const store = mockStore({});
    await store.dispatch(actions.loadScreen());
    expect(window.location).toEqual('www.google.com');
    console.log(window.location.href); // top property on window is Unforgeable
  });
});
```

`jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
}
```

package versions:

```json
"jest": "^26.6.3",
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/67339402/screen.actions.test.js (10.31 s)
  67339402
    ✓ should pass (19 ms)

  console.log
    www.google.com

      at examples/67339402/screen.actions.js:3:11

  console.log
    undefined

      at examples/67339402/screen.actions.test.js:21:13

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.698 s
```

Comment: @slideshop2 Thank you for taking the time out for the detailed response! Much appreciated